# Why doesnt my main class run the method i called?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dao

i have a question: i am trying to make an insert-query with in java using the jdbc for mysql. I think my code is correct, but somehow i can't run the method i call in my main class. Here's my method i wanna call code:

```
public void wijzigAfspraak() {
    try {
        Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
        String query2 = "";
        rs = stmt2.executeQuery(query2);
        System.out.println("query uitgevoerd");

        while (rs.next()){
            String titel = rs.getString(1);
            String datum = rs.getString(2);
            int urgentie = rs.getInt(3);
            String beschrijving = rs.getString(4);
            System.out.println(titel+datum+urgentie+beschrijving);
    }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

here is my main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

AfspraakDaoImpl adi = new AfspraakDaoImpl();
Afspraak afs = new Afspraak("","",1,"");
afs.setTitel("hond");
afs.setAfspraakDatum("12juni");
afs.setUrgentie(123);
afs.setBeschrijving("test");
adi.voegAfspraakToe();

adi.wijzigAfspraak();
```

}

my console doesn't print anything and my database shows no difference in data, which means it didn't work right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you are starting the correct `main()` method? How are you launching the application? From an IDE, from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're executing empty SQL query here:

```
String query2 = "";
rs = stmt2.executeQuery(query2);
```

If you want to execute INSERT statement, You should invoke `executeUpdate()` method on you statement object `stmt2` and pass SQL string as a parameter.

Moreover, consider using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` as follows:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO foo(value) VALUES(?)";
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString(1, "bar");
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

One more thing. Looks like you keep `ResultSet rs` as a class field. Don't do so, try to minimize number of mutable state variables of your class, try to keep your components light and stateless. It's better to keep `Statement` and `ResultSet`in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a DAO and using MYSQL Database ( witch is not specified here ;) ):

```
public void wijzigAfspraak(String 1, String 2, String 3, etc..) {
try {
    Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
    String query2 = "insert into afspraken (column_1, column_2, etc...)    values ( String 1, String 2, etc..)"; --> these values come from the wijzigafspraak(String 1, String 2, etc..)
    stm2.executeUpdate(query2);
    System.out.println("query is inserted correctly");
```

You do not want to use the rs.next(), witch is used for a "SELECT-STATEMENT", you do not receive data, vut you insert it.

then, your main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

AfspraakDaoImpl adi = new AfspraakDaoImpl();
Afspraak afs = new Afspraak("","",1,"");
afs.setTitel("hond");
afs.setAfspraakDatum("12juni");
afs.setUrgentie(123);
afs.setBeschrijving("test");
//adi.voegAfspraakToe();//this is not specified?? and probably does not work either

adi.wijzigAfspraak(afs.getTitel(), afs.getAfspraakDatum(), etc..);
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your sql statement ? It should be :

```
String query2 = "select titel,datum,urgentie,beschrijving from Afspraak";
```